# How do I identify the connected USB device?

Tags: kernel, usb, udev, tty, c

If I write the rules, for example, in this form:

```
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="serial_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="serial_end"

KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", RUN+="/<path-to-my-script>/myscript.sh %k"

LABEL="serial_end"
```

then, when I connect the USB device `tty`, I will be able to get its name, which installed the device in the directory `/dev/ttyUSB*`.

How can I find out exactly this name if I want to monitor connections in a C program?

[image]

`dmesg` allows me to see the device and immediately see the two ports that the kernel creates in `/dev`. Is there an API that will allow me to see this in C?

I tried using the `udev` library, but the device it defines is located in `bus/usb/...`, but I need exactly the name of the serial port that the driver creates - `ttyUSB*`.

P.S. Or is it possible to somehow find out this name from under the `udev` library, knowing that the device is located, for example, here `/dev/bus/usb/002/047`?

Comment: wouldn't it make most sense to use that rule to *name* the device exactly as you would like it, instead of figuring out the name afterwards?

Comment: The fact is that I just want to create a link to the device based on its name, because the device index `ttyUSB*`, which is a numeric value, is a specific port. My device creates two ports that I connect to, so I need to understand how to distinguish between these ports. That's why I want to get these names so that I can create the right ports based on the index, while not generating a bunch of other links.

Comment: but then the /sys/bus/usb/devices view is exactly what you need: the devices you have, named by the bus / port they're connected to.

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... you can easily copy the text output of `dmesg` and paste it into your post ... format it as code